# create simple txt file and read from it objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create mock implementation of server. I have several json-files.

I want to add these files to the xcode project, and then read from them in the application.

In android we have assets folder. And we can place there files, and they will be installed with the application.

Is there any asset folder in ios to store files, and how to read files from there?

Comment: In a folder in the app bundle, perhaps?

Comment: @trojanfoe would this files from bundle be stored to the app? how to have access to those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS App Bundle is the main directory. If you put your file there you can read as such:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

This will read file myFile.txt

Comment: Don't forget you need to copy the `.txt` into the app bundle during a build.

Comment: @dorian the root folder of the project is the bundle folder?

Comment: @JenyaKyrmyza yes you can think it as your root folder.

Comment: great, glad to help :)